# Binary is invalidated automatically in Apple TestFlight environment

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, ipa, apple-developer-account

While I'm pushing iOS application to TestFlight, every time I see error message **status changed to invalid binary**. 
I've listed steps below what I performed while pushing the build to TestFlight .

1. Clean build in Xcode
2. Archive the build by incrementing the build number
3. In Archive window, **Validate** the build and once validation is **success**
4. Click **Distribute App** to "App store connect"
5. Followed all steps appears until "upload" button shown
6. Click on **Upload** button
7. Xcode shows build uploaded successfully
8. Logon to Appstore connect account
9. Under the TestFlight , I can see latest build is **processing**
10. After ~5 minutes I no longer see my latest build which was showing **processing** few minutes ago. In my iPad (I've installed AppStoreConnect application), I received notification that **status changed to invalid binary**.

I had submitted plenty of builds under the same developer account to TestFlight without any issues in the past, but since a week I'm getting this issue. I don't receive any mail from Apple as well why my binary status changed to invalid binary. I also tried my old codebase which I had submitted earlier without any issues to same TestFlight account, still the issue remains same with no clue.

Environment details

- Xcode 11.3
- App OS version 13.0
- Mac OS version 10.14.6
- My Apple developer account is active and valid.

If any of you have noticed this issue, help on resolving this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: any progress on this?  I am experiencing the exact same issue with XCode 11.4.

Comment: No @MikeyE, its still unresolved. We are working with Apple on the same. Let me know if you find any solution.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem.  In my case, I had failed to read the emails sent by Apple's system.  One indicated my app includes a geo location data file, but is not marked as a navigation type app.  When I removed the geo location data file and re-submitted it worked without error.